# ifelse statement with iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, if-statement

I have an iframe and i would like to make an if condition that if the iframe source is equal to a speciefied page a div should show:

**Example**

```
if(getElementById('iframe').src = 'someurl'){
getElementById('div').style.display. = 'block';
}
```

**The Problem**

I am not an expert in JS but when I use this script the iframe loads "someurl" automatically asoon as the main page is loaded, which I don't want, I want the div to be displayed when the iframe source changes to "someurl" via a link. The link is working fine and it changes the iframe src but the if statement isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `=` is an **assignment**
- `==` is an equality test
- `===` is an equality test without type casting (and is generally prefered to `==`

Use `===`, not `=`.

Then you need to reference `getElementById` correctly. It is a method of the `document` object, not a global.

Use `document.getElementById` not `getElementById`

Then, you'll need to get rid of the trailing `.` character from your display property.

Then, assuming you want to update this when a link in the frame is followed and not just when a link in the current page is followed, you need to rerun the function periodically to see if it has changed.

```
setInterval(yourFunctionName, 5000);
```

Then, since the page might move away from the URL you are looking for, you need to add an else statement

```
function yourFunctionName () {
    var div = document.getElementById('div'); /* Really? Your unique ID for a specific div is 'div'?! */
    if(document.getElementById('iframe').src === 'someurl'){
        div.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

Comment: yeh I know the document.getElementById :) just forgot it :) I'm a beginner incase you didn't notice :D. Thanks a lot, i figured out that == works just as much as === does, I did try == once but it didn't work maybe I had a typo, but thanks for explaining

Comment: I'm using onLoad function inside the iframe to run the script so it updates as soon as the iframe loads a new page :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(document.getElementById('iframe').src == 'someurl'){
          document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

use `==` instead of `=` you are assign value to the src instead of checking for condition.

use `==` or `===`

Comment: Remove **.** after `style.display` too

Comment: @Adeel thanks for the correction. where did u get your avatar.  just curious =)

Comment: it was created online almost 2 years ago, but don't know the website name now :(

Comment: @Adeel i've been looking for that site for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in

```
if(getElementById('iframe').src = 'someurl')
```

`=` is assignment, but you should check condition. Use `==`. You can swap condition, to eliminate errors, like this. Here is an example:

```
if('someurl' == getElementById('iframe').src)
```

The basick idea is than constant should be left part of comparision. And if you accidentally write assignment instead of comparison, i'll get more clear error.