# show iframe if external .php is available only. else: hide it

Tags: iframe

If there is no content to display (ad banner delivered by external server), i want hide the iframe (e.g the div that includes the iframe).
This is what i have so far, but it is not working. Other solutions had the "cross-origin" problem.

Iframe hidden by default, check if external .php available. If yes, display it.

```
<script>
$.get('https://www.external-example.com/subolder/myid.php', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // make the ad visible
    $('#iframe-container').show();
});
</script>

<div id="iframe-container" style="visibility: hidden;">
<div style="display:inline-block;width:auto;height:auto;">
  <iframe src="https://www.external-example.com/subolder/myid.php" style="background-color: white;border: 0;height: auto;text-align:center;width: auto;max-height: 100%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

*script example from: [How do hide div if ad does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222363/how-do-hide-div-if-ad-does-not-appear)

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992135/6478701) could help you ?

Comment: results in a second script i don`t get working. i will try to work with one code first before looking for another one. In the other example (your link) i do not understand what "id" the script is looking for.
e.g  if(document.getElementById('iframe').src === 'someurl'){
is this script looking for id 'iframe' in the file "someurl"? confused now

Comment: I agree the the OP from that post didn't use very friendly IDs. What he was trying to achieve there is perform a test (on the contents of the iframe) and choose to display/not display a div based on the results from that test. You can probably apply this to you scenario. Instead of hiding 'div', you would need to hide your iframe

Comment: is my written code at top completely wrong or are there mistakes as ' == .. ?