# javascript: hide the div if external .php file has .. inline style never changes

Tags: javascript

story: hide the iframe if the .php is deleted or similar. So i try to hide the div that contains the iframe. Website of customer A can iframe a video from my website (external-website). But if the video is deleted, it should hide the complete iframe (the div). The complete php will be deleted or renamed if the video is not available.

Hide the `<div>` if external file (i want to iframe)
is not available or named as .php?=123456 or has not a `<div "id"`, **whatever**.

**The inline style never changes.**

I tried each of this above, i don`t get it working.
I can edit the external .php file (my website too).
I do not get the script to change the inline style whatever i try.

What i want to do, hide the div if "something".

```
<div id="hide-me">
  <iframe src="https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php" style="background-color: white;border: 0;height: auto;text-align:center;width: auto;max-height: 100%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
function yourFunctionName () {
    var anyname = document.getElementById("hide-me").style.display;
    if(document.getElementById("id-in-external-php").src == 'https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php'){
        document.getElementById("hide-me").style.display="block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("hide-me").style.display="none";
    }

}
</script>
```

I asked a similar question here, but it did not give a solution
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299717/show-iframe-if-external-php-is-available-only-else-hide-it)

content of https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php :

```
<div id="id-in-external-php">this is content for the iframe</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ran your code again and it worked, so you can try it:

```
<div id="hide-me" style="display: none;">
    <iframe style="display: none;" id="id-in-external-php" src="https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php" style="background-color: white;border: 0;height: auto;text-align:center;width: auto;max-height: 100%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
  const yourFunctionName = () => {
    const anyname = document.getElementById("hide-me");
    const frameId = document.getElementById("id-in-external-php");
    const check = frameId.contentDocument.body.children
    const c = check[0].innerText;
    if(c.startsWith('Cannot')) {
      anyname.style.display="none";
      frameId.style.display="none";
    } else {
      anyname.style.display="block";
      frameId.style.display="block";
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", yourFunctionName, false);
</script>
```

I did not see where you invoked the function, so i invoked mine when window load

Comment: i deleted the id "id-in-external-php"  in https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php but still <div id="hide-me" style="display: block;">
What iam missing? Shouldnt it change to display:none ?

Comment: external .php file:
<div id="id-in-external-php">this is content for the iframe</div>

Comment: The iFrame content will only be hidden if the src which is "https://www.external-website.com/subfolder/1250.php" is wrong. Eg change it to "https://www.external-website.com/subfolder.php" and you will notice that the iframe content will be hidden. I edited the main code, just hide the div initially and display it via javascript

Comment: changed the file name of the external .php from 1250.php to deleted1250.php.
Still results in <div id="hide-me" style="display: block;"> and the iframe with: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server. 
I will have a look if made something wrong while changing the real path names. But i think, no.

Comment: I tried the last edited main code too. renamed ,same result. display:block
and the iframe with: Not Found The req..

Comment: same result. Iframe visible and iframe content "not found the request url.."
i copied and pasted the code for testing here: https://js.do/

Comment: I have been working on it, Sorry for the delay. Check the new code please

Comment: thank you. is "cannot" the error message from server as text?
Nice idea, not sure if i understood it. Aren`t the error messages as:<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>

tested your updated code:
"JavaScript error: TypeError: check[0] is undefined on line 13"
or "JavaScript error: TypeError: frameId.contentDocument is null on line 12"

Comment: tested your updated code:
"JavaScript error: TypeError: check[0] is undefined on line 13"
or "JavaScript error: TypeError: frameId.contentDocument is null on line 12"

Comment: Console. Log check to see how you get the response. Mine was <body> <pre>Cannot Get ......</pre></body>

Comment: i think it depends on each browser e.g edge, firefox,chrome.. 
also the js.do test gives the error message